# Using cp to replace a directory of the same name

Tags: cp

How can I make `cp` replace a directory of the same name without removing the existing directory first? `cp`'s default behaviour is to copy the source directory into the destination rather than replace it:

```
mkdir -p test/a
mkdir a
cp -a test/a a
```

`a` is now within `a`, it didn't replace `a`. How can I make `cp` replace directories? I want it to work the same way it does with files.

I could of course delete the target first, but I don't want to have to run more than one command :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a dot `.` after `a`:

```
cp -a test/a/. a
```

It actually does not replace `a` as you though. It just copy `test/a` content to directory `a`.

Comment: I just tested it, although it might not replace the directory itself it does indeed work in the same manner as replacing the directory. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk does the thing ;)

```
cp -a test/a/* a
```

Comment: This won't copy hidden files.

Comment: @Gnouc , cool...you're the man again ;) , hey but that wasnt the main point of the OPs question ;)